# iOS Widget not available in Widget Search (for only 50% of users)?

Tags: ios, iphone, widget

We are running into a major issue with building an iOS Widget. iOS Widgets are basically large informational app icons you can pin to your iPhone home screen ([What is a widget?](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207122#:%7E:text=Add%20widgets%20to%20your%20Home,Tap%20Done.)). iOS widgets were introduced in iOS 14.

We’ve finished building our iOS widget. However, when half of our users attempt to search for our widget after downloading our app, our widget is not showing up in the widget search results. For the other half, it works fine. This seems to be somewhat of a bug from Apple, as it is affects other widget apps ([Apple Thread](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/679097), [the problem exists for large widget apps also](https://www.tiktok.com/@erzeltristen/video/7055742325347257646?lang=en)). It seems like we are having this issue far more, percentage-wise, than other widget apps. I’ve searched through nearly every resource online (StackOverflow, etc.), which is why I’m posting a question now. Things like deleting the app and reinstalling, restarting the phone, etc. have not been a fix either for these problematic users.

It doesn't seem to be tied to any iOS version (14, 15, etc.). As I have iOS 15, and it works fine. But, some users with iOS 15 are getting the bug.

Has anyone ran into this issue where a widget is not searchable? How did you fix it? Any resources are appreciated as I am at a major blocker right now. Since my app is primarily based on iOS widgets, this makes it basically unusable for certain users.

Comment: It seems many users are facing this issue, but there might be a case facing your users that they haven't opened the app at least once. Users have to open the app at least once before they can add the widget. Otherwise, it won't show in their widget search.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of the "bug" where the user can't see widgets if you haven't opened the app at least once. I can recreate that bug easily. But, these users have definitely opened the app multiple times.

Comment: Did you find the solution same here. one version up widgets were working fine as soon as I reinstall app widgets arent there now.

Comment: Also seeing this issue, did anyone find a solution?

Comment: Check my answer that I just posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my own issue. The app's deployment target was only targeted at iOS 17. Therefore, whenever someone had iOS 16, the user couldn't search the widget. The solution is to make sure that your widgets target iOS deployment goes back a couple iOS versions. Otherwise, those users will never be able to use it.

And make sure to check the iOS versions of both targets (the widget and the iOS app).